How to modify desktop file of an application to apply to all windows it creates?
I have a Linux executable, for which I have created a .desktop file. When I am in the main menu of the game, GNOME recognizes this and correctly puts a dot under the icon in the dock.

In this state, when I call xprop, I get the following WMClass entry: WM_CLASS(STRING) = "War Thunder (Vulkan, 64bit)", "War Thunder (Vulkan, 64bit)"
However, when I am in the game in the game, the icon changes to the following:

And when I inspect the window with xprop, I get the following entry: WM_CLASS(STRING) = "War Thunder (Vulkan, 64bit) - In battle", "War Thunder (Vulkan, 64bit) - In battle"

My .desktop file looks as follows:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=War Thunder
Exec=/opt/WarThunder/linux64/aces
Icon=/opt/WarThunder/launcher.ico
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
StartupWMClass=War Thunder (Vulkan, 64bit)

What I'd like to know is, how can I edit my .desktop entry so that both windows get the icon, or ideally are just recognized as the same window, since no additional window is ever opened, just the WMClass is changed.
